# How can I search for and then copy the lines in vi/vim?

Tags: vim, clipboard, vi

I guess it is better to explain with an example, so here it is:

```
My useful line.
Some useless line.
Some other useless line.
Another useful line - oh I want this!
This is useful, I want this too!
```

In this example, I am searching for the string "useful". So, I want to copy lines 1, 4 and 5 to clipboard. How can I do this with vim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First clear register `a` (you can use any letter a-z) for using.

```
:let @a=''
```

Then run the magic.

```
:g/useful/yank A
```

It will search for lines matching pattern "useful" and then run command `:yank A` to them. Capital A will append to the register `a`.

If your vim is configured with global Windows/X clipboards, you can run

```
:let @+=@a
```

to copy the register `a`'s content to the clipboard.

Comment: @pb2q: clever! Haven't seen that one :)

Comment: Clearing register short and sweet: `qaq`